# My icloud photos won't upload onto my new macbook air 2018

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud, photos, data-transfer

[image]

I just got this computer 2 days ago and the number of photos its trying to upload keeps climbing, but the bar won't show it's loading. It did at one point and it seemed to be done after a bit, but then it went back to the beginning. Is this something that will just take time? Also, I can't plug my phone into the computer to upload because it doesn't have a USB port (computer came out a couple weeks ago so the charging holes and stuff are new and different.) All the icloud settings say my devices are connected but it's just not working, anyone have advice?It also keeps pausing to "save battery power" which is annoying and I wish I could turn that off. Help?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  You have a lot of photos and the Mac doesn't upload them all at once.  It's designed to upload them in the background, when you're on power, and when you're connected to wifi.  Just let it go for a few more days.  Be sure you have enough iCloud storage, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this found [here:](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204967)

> If your Photos library won't open, or if Photos behaves unexpectedly,
>   the Photos library repair tool might resolve the issues.
>
> Follow these steps to use the Photos library repair tool:
>
> Hold down the Option and Command keys while you open Photos on your
>   Mac. In the dialog that appears, click Repair to start the repair
>   process. You might be asked to type in your user account password to
>   authorize the library repair.
>
> The repair tool analyzes the the library's database and repairs any
>   inconsistencies it detects. Depending on the size of your library,
>   this might take some time. When the process is completed, Photos opens
>   the library.